What's the difference between nestjs onApplicationBootstrap and onModuleInit in nestjs, and which one should I choose?
Suppose I need to run some code on app start, for example, db.connect(), it seems that I can do it either on module init or on application bootstrap without much difference, and none of which seems semenatic more suitable than the other, how do I choose between them?
